# jest doesn't import ES6 modules (with correct transformIgnorePatterns)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I'm running Jest and getting error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    /atol/node-service/node_modules/atol-atoms/Grids/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import _Row from "./Row";
                                                                                                    ^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    > 1 | import {Container, Row, Cell} from 'atol-atoms/Grids';
```

Where `atol-atoms` is a library of components which I need to transform with babel to use. Its' work with webpack, but when I'm running tests it's failed.

**My dependencies:**

```
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.6.0",
"@babel/polyfill": "^7.6.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.0",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
"babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
"jest": "^24.9.0",
```

I supposed that next config in `jest.config.js` should work if I need transform modules from `node_modules` with `babel-jest`:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
        '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(atol-atoms)/)'
],
```

Also, I have correct .babelrc with `env.test` section:

```
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
      ],
      "presets": [
        [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            "debug": true
          }
        ],
        "@babel/preset-react"
      ]
    }
```